# Passing user object to view results in "user is not defined" with Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I've been trying to learn node lately using the Express and SailsJS frameworks and with both i've struggled with passing data to the EJS view.

I'm following the correct convention of passing data to the view using `{data: 'This is the data'}` however I'm constantly having issues with this data persisting.

Sails app with passport for authentication. I can both signup users and login however using conditionals in the view and passing data is always a problem.

AuthContoller.js

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {

    _config: {
        actions: false,
      shortcuts: false,
      rest: false
    },

    login: function(req, res) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        return res.send({
          message: info.message,
          user: user
        });
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err, user) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        return res.view('homepage', {
          message: info.message,
          user: user
        });
      });

    })(req, res);
     },

  logout: function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  }

};
```

Then the part of the view i'm trying to show a logout button when a user is logged in and hide it when logged out. But I constantly get a user is not defined error for the view.

homepage.ejs

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="/signup">Signup</a></li>
  <% if (user) { %>
    <li><%= user.email %></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
  <% } else { %>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

I don't know if i'm supposed to save the user in the session, or if it's something to do with locals or the view syntax but i've tried multiple solutions with no luck. Had the same issues with Express too.

I've tried using `if (locals.user)` in the view and that stops the errors but it doesn't change the view.

TL;DR: I basically want to create a user object once a user is logged in that can display details in the view, accessible to multiple pages. And know what to do when a user who hasn't signed up visits the webpage and no user object has been created yet.

Comment: Two debugging tips: in your ejs, instead of `if (user)`, you could try `if (typeof(user) !== 'undefined')`, sometimes templaters can handle that more gracefully. Also, try `sails.log(user);` right before your `res.view` call, to see if it has the values you expect before you pass it to the view. It might have to do with your passport's deserialize method.

Comment: The first part worked, it's strange because i've already tried that and it hadn't worked for me. Maybe i'd changed the code so much that another part broke. Thanks a million.

Only issue is if I click another link on the page the menu reverts back as if the user object had disappeared. Whats the correct way to have the user persist?

Comment: The above code is from your authcontroller... in it you expressly pass the `user` to your `homepage.ejs` view. You may have to do the same thing in each controller/view where you want the user to be present. The good news is that passport provides middleware that will load logged in users into the `req` object. If the user is logged in, `req.user` should be that user object, so you'll have access to it in all controllers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I've been trying to solve this the past two days. I added `if (typeof(req.user) !== 'undefined')` and output the user details using `req.user.email` and that's done the trick. Appreciate the help.

Comment: We've all been stuck! Just enjoy that great unstuck feeling for the next couple of minutes!